# With AngularJS can I do an advanced search for a range of numbers in a field?

Tags: angularjs

I am retrieving data rows. Here's the code that does the display of the rows for me.

```
<tr 
    data-ng-show="grid.data.length > 0" 
    data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | orderBy:problemSortField.key:inverse">
```

Each of the rows has a problemId field and I would like to be able to show every problemID or just those in a range.

Is there a way that I could have some kind of search that would allow me to for example limit the number of rows to those with problemId in a range?

So for example I would like to just retrieve those rows for problemId  5-10 or for all problemIds

I know that I can do some kind of search for a specific Id but is there a way I could do this for a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the *filter* filter does:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in grid.data | filter:isProblemIdInRange | orderBy:...">

$scope.isProblemIdInRange(row) {
    return row.problemId >= 5 && row.problemId < 10;
}
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I could make two input elements that I could use to decide the start and end range.